Battery-Inverter-Converter Circular Flow
I am wiring up a switch in my travel trailer to go between shore power and inverter power.  It makes sense to switch at the main 120v AC input that feeds my power distribution panel, and then switch between the shore plug and the inverter. This way my switch is upstream from everything else and controls all 120v power coming in, including completely off.
But the converter also plugs into the power distribution panel and sends 12v power back to the battery.  So, this is circular.  And I don't ever want my inverter to wastefully power the converter going from 12v to 120v and back to 12v.
But this won't happen... right?  The battery isn't going to draw current from the converter feed line while it is supplying current to the inverter.
Or, how will this work?  It's just so much easier and simple to put the switch up front at the main 120v power in, rather than splice it into the circuit that feeds just my outlets, because I would like the option to power all the 120v circuits.
I think this was only partly discussed here, but I have zero interest in the silliness of thinking I could charge my own batteries from my own batteries!  I only found that question because it sounded similar.

Post a diagram of your current set up and we'll tell you how to fix it.

Sounds like you want to do this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Good idea.  So you're saying, don't use the built-in outlet on the power distribution panel to plugin the charger/converter since that can't be separated from the circuit.  Instead wire a new socket that is only on the shore power line and plug the charger into that.  This way the charger/converter will only operate when you switch to shore power.  This makes sense.

One problem with this, is the charger loses the benefit of the 15a breaker on the power distribution panel.  So I would have to wire in a separate breaker on the line for the charger.

@jhickok Ask your self this: is there anytime you would power the charger from the panel and NOT exclusively from the shore power?

@jhickok you may or may not need to wire a separate breaker. Depends on your charger. Sometimes they have breakers on the front panel. Or on the back.

This converter/charger has no breaker... just fuses for the DC side.

@jhickok I don't know your set up, but the easiest and cheapest way to deal with it could be adding an inline fuse at the charger feed.
